# H2 version change issue from 1.4.200 to 2.0.202?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, h2, maven-surefire-plugin

I upgraded my springboot H2 dependency from 1.4.200 to 2.0.202 , but getting the below exception . Could you please help.

```
    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: 
Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT [*]VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'MODE'"; expected "TOP, DISTINCT, ALL, *, INTERSECTS, NOT, EXISTS, UNIQUE, INTERSECTS"; SQL statement:
SELECT VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'MODE' [42001-210]
```

Answer (score 7):

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` in H2 2.x.y is not compatible with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` from H2 1.x.y.

You need to use

```sql
SELECT SETTING_VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE SETTING_NAME = 'MODE'
```

with new versions of H2.

If this query was executed by Flyway, you need to upgrade it to 8.2.2 or any newer version, older versions don't support recent versions of H2.

You also need to check versions of other libraries, for example, if you use Hibernate ORM, you need to upgrade it to 5.6.5.Final (or later version). Older versions also don't support H2 2.x.y.

Please also note that H2 2.0.202 is an old release with many new features and also many bugs and regressions, it will be better to use H2 2.1.210, it contains various important fixes.

Comment: Hi , Where to execute this(SELECT SETTING_VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE SETTING_NAME = 'MODE'
) ? .

Comment: You don't need to execute it anywhere. You need to find which part of your application executes query with old column names (`VALUE` and `NAME`) and update this part. It can be Flyway, some other library, or own code of your application.

Comment: it will be executed by Flyway , as i remember. So i can update the flyway to latest and hibernate to latest and test ?

Comment: Yes, you need to upgrade them too together with H2, because their old versions don't work with new versions of H2.

Comment: Hi After updating H2 to latest version( 2.1.210) and Flywaydb to 8.5.0 version getting the below Exception:      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate()I

Comment: could you please help me to the earliest as i urgently need to fix vulnerabilities of H2  and its pending from last sprint.

Comment: You need to upgrade Spring Boot too, its old versions don't work with Flyway 7.x.y and 8.x.y.

Comment: I am working on latest spring release version which is 2.3.12.RELEASE..

Comment: The latest version of Spring Boot is actually 2.6.3. You can't use old versions of `spring-boot-autoconfigure` with recent versions of Flyway.