# How to upgrade from flyway 5.2.4 to 9.0.1?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, h2, flyway

I have spring boot 2.7.0 maven project that uses flyway 5.2.4. I need to upgrade flyway to newer version.

It all started because I needed to update h2 and h2gis-functions so that I could use h2 1.4.200 or newer due to new features that I needed from h2 v 1.4.200.
I currently had `com.h2database:h2:1.4.197` and `org.orbisgis:h2gis-functions:1.3.2` dependencies in my pom.xml. Those 2 need to be compatible with each other. As I understood not all versions are compatible. So I decided to try if `com.h2database:h2:2.1.214` and `org.orbisgis:h2gis:2.1.0` work or not

After doing it I started to get error that I previously did not get:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT [*]VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'info.BUILD_ID'"; expected "DISTINCT, ALL, *, INTERSECTS (, NOT, EXISTS, UNIQUE, INTERSECTS"; SQL statement: SELECT VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'info.BUILD_ID' [42001-214]
```

Which I learned was caused by old flyway. In my project in pom.xml I have flyway 5.2.4. After googling the issue I ran into this stackoverflow post: [H2 version change issue from 1.4.200 to 2.0.202?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71202470/h2-version-change-issue-from-1-4-200-to-2-0-202)

Which has similar error (Couldn't find exact same error). There it was suggested that poster should upgrade flyway to 8.2.2 or any newer version. I am not exactly sure if I necessarily need flyway 9.0.1 or if any older version is also fine but looks like I need some newer version of flyway.

After updating flyway version to 9.0.1 and try to run tests the application does not start anymore.

The error I get is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration.ignoreMissingMigrations(Z)Lorg/flywaydb/core/api/configuration/FluentConfiguration;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
    ... 207 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration.ignoreMissingMigrations(Z)Lorg/flywaydb/core/api/configuration/FluentConfiguration;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 219 more
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration.ignoreMissingMigrations(Z)Lorg/flywaydb/core/api/configuration/FluentConfiguration;
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.configureIgnoredMigrations(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:264)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.configureProperties(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:205)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.flyway(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 220 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration.ignoreMissingMigrations(Z)Lorg/flywaydb/core/api/configuration/FluentConfiguration;
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:975)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1000)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1394)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandles.java:1750)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:477)
    ... 228 more
```

How to fix `NoSuchMethodError`?

Answer (score 8):

This error comes up because method `ignoreMissingMigrations` was deprecated in Flyway 8.x and removed in Flyway 9.x.
See this:
https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3484

Because even the latest Spring Boot (2.7.2 as of now) still uses `ignoreMissingMigrations` in `FlywayAutoConfiguration` class the only ways to solve this are **either**:

- Use Flyway 8.x
- Disable Spring `FlywayAutoConfiguration` and use manually written FlywayConfiguration to configure Flyway while using Flyway 9.x

Comment: Tnx! With FW 8.2.2 I started to get `org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to calculate checksum of V5_57__file_name.sql
Input length = 1` That file worked with old FW 5.2.4. The sql file itself is just a normal insert statement with some TO_CLOB('blah blah blah')s in it.  That TO_CLOB contains some finnish/swedish letters such as ä, å, ö. Coud that be a problem? Further down it is caused by `MalformedInputException: Input length = 1` It does not say exactly where in the file problem is.

Comment: @u4963840 Yes, that's most probably the case. They have modified slightly checksum calculation in 6.x:
https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2744#issuecomment-607339091
See the issue details:
https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2744
Most probably this: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2744#issuecomment-620075048 is your case

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that post myself too. But It says "I guess the simplest workaround is to expand ä into ae". In my case it's not really an option because those migrations end up in production where we need to deal with real ä not ae. And since it would mean having to go back to hack already applied migrations in live env then I dont think I get approval for this solution. I guess it's a "won't fix" on their side as it's been already since 2020 and it's 2022 now?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can use `flyway repair` to recompute checksums:
- https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/repair

Similar case here, where they used repair to fix it:
https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2474#issuecomment-522962377

Comment: Could you provide an example on disabling the FlywayAutoConfiguration and how to manually configure it?

Comment: @swordgit:
You would need to copy-paste Spring-Boot auto configuration into your config folder - it will override Springs' config and tweak it according (as you can't really extend it because all interesting stuff is private). Here is an example:
https://github.com/valb3r/flyway_9_spring_2_7_2-issue

Comment: Thank. I fixed it by setting on build.gradle:
implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:8.5.12'